# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found tomcat spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I started learning spring and cant win tomcat server.

[This is file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8aYV.png)

This is web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[this is dispatcher-servlet.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTT7K.png)

And MainController

```
package com.burmistrov;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
@Controller
public class MainController {`

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String view() {
        return "hello";
    }}
```

[And default settings of Tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9xC0.png)

Anyone can help me, where did i make a mistake?

Comment: You entered a URL in your browser that is not mapped to any servlet.

Comment: @Selaron mapping "/" in controller should return page

Comment: You did not mention context path of your app nor the URL you actually visit in the browser, so this was just a plausible guess.

Comment: @Selaron Then what solution?

Comment: @ДенисБурмистров Check my answer, and give a shout !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `web.xml` you didn't configure `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. That's why you are getting error.

add this code at your `web.xml`

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
   <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Comment: @ДенисБурмистров Can you update your `web.xml` after edition !

Comment: @ДенисБурмистров I mean recent `web.xml` file in your project

Comment: in your `contex-param` remove `webapp/` this part. And move this section after `servlet-mapping`

Answer (score 0):

You are visiting a page that isn't mapped in your program, so the server doesn't know what to do and sends a 404. You will have to map the page you are visiting.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hello.jsp under you /WEB-INF/jsp directory or add Annotation @ResponseBody on MainController.view as below,

```
package com.burmistrov;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
@Controller
public class MainController {`

@GetMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public String view() {
    return "hello";
}}
```

Hope this helps.